# freeradius dynamic client by python or rest

Tags: python, freeradius

I have some implementation of freeradius that use rlm_python and some implementation using rlm_rest for Authorization.

I cannot figureout how to implementing dynamic client using rlm_python or rlm_rest.

Could you please give me some configuration sample on it, since all docs I read is about mysql, file, and ldap.

Sincerely
-bino-

Comment: So isn't request for resources. Do your research, try it out and when something fails, ask a question about the failing part.

Comment: thankyou @user1767754. Currently ... my solution is that my application generated a temporary clients file, and set the 'dynamic-client' part to read from it. but I want it more dynamic. Could you please point me to a starting point to do more research ?

Comment: https://wiki.freeradius.org/modules/Rlm_python

Comment: @user1767754, since I already write authorization backend using rlm_pythpon and rlm_rest means that I also read that documentation already. The things that I don't know is how to use rlm_python for 'dynamic client'. thanks anyway.

Comment: You call out to rlm_rest or rlm_python in the dynamic clients virtual server, and provide the correct attributes.  There are many examples here: https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v4.0.x/raddb/sites-available/dynamic-clients

Comment: thankyou @ArranCudbard-Bell . so, all I need is modify the 'new client' section right ?